# How can I dial the phone from Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am building a Flutter app, and I'd like to dial a phone number in response to a button tap. What's the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Check Latest Answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/67722228/1318946

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Typically, to interact with the underlying platform, you have to write platform specific code and communicate with the same using [platform channels](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/). However, Flutter provides some points of integration with the platform out of the box. To dial the phone for instance, you can use the [UrlLauncher.launch](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/UrlLauncher-class.html) API with the `tel` scheme to dial the phone.

Something like `UrlLauncher.launch("tel://<phone_number>");` should work fine on all platforms.

Do note that this will not work in the simulators. So make sure you are using an actual device to test this.

Comment: Is more low-level phone activity possible too? I'm thinking about creating a full replacement dialer app and I'm wondering whether it could be done in flutter.

Comment: Link to `UrlLauncher` does not work anymore, the function seems to have been moved to a new package: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher

Comment: "Do note that this will not work in the simulators." - thank you very much!

Comment: Don't forget to add queries/permissions.
Look through "Configuration" section.
https://pub.dev/documentation/url_launcher/latest/

Answer (score 93):

This method will open the dialer :

```dart
_launchCaller() async {
    const url = "tel:1234567";   
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
       await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }   
}
```

EDIT:

In case anybody facing errors:

Add `url_launcher:` in the pubspec.yaml & run `flutter get`

Also `import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';`

Comment: This should be the correct & accepted answer. This is working perfectly fine. Same reference was found at : https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher

Comment: Don't forget to add queries/permissions.
Look through "Configuration" section.
https://pub.dev/documentation/url_launcher/latest/

Answer (score 9):

You can use the url_launcher widget (https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)

1. Add this to your package's pubspec.yaml file: `dependencies: url_launcher: ^5.7.10`
2. Install it: `$ flutter pub get`
3. Import it `import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';`
4. Inside your class, define this method so you can call from any action in your code:

   ```
    Future<void> _makePhoneCall(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
   ```

   }
5. inside the build widget:

   ```
    IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.phone),
       onPressed: () 
       {
          setState(() {
             _makePhoneCall('tel:0597924917');
          });
       },
     ),
   ```

Note 1: you should write the phone number with prefix 'tel': 'tel:0123456789'

Note 2: sometimes it will not work well until you close the app in your mobile and reopen it, so flutter can inject the code of the new widget successfully.

Answer (score 7):

Use [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher).

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
    
openDialPad(String phoneNumber) async {
    Uri url = Uri(scheme: "tel", path: phoneNumber);
    if (await canLaunchUrl(url)) {
      await launchUrl(url);
    } else {
       print("Can't open dial pad.");
    }
}
```

Note: Don't forgot to update `info.plist` and `AndroidManifest.xml` as per the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

Follow the below steps:

1. add the `url_launcher: Latest version` dependency in your pubspec.yaml
2. Go to `\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml`.
3. add the queries lines before the **<application**, like this :

   ```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.flutter">
        <queries>
            <intent>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
                <data android:scheme="tel" />
            </intent>
        </queries>
       <application ...
   ```

For more queries, follow this [more queries](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher#android)

4.Add the dialer function, and set the url, `final url ="tel:$phoneNumber"`; like this:

```
  Future<void> dialNumber(
      {required String phoneNumber, required BuildContext context}) async {
    final url = "tel:$phoneNumber";
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      ShowSnackBar.showSnackBar(context, "Unable to call $phoneNumber");
    }

    return;
  }
```

5. **Done**

Comment: This works for me, don't forget to add 

<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>sms</string>
        <string>tel</string>
</array>

in your info.plist

Answer (score 5):

This is what worked for me as of **January 2023**

**NB**: The major difference from the other answers above is my **#4**

**ALSO**: You can now use test this in **Emulator**

**Steps:**

1.Add `url_launcher: latest` to `pubspec.yaml`

2.Configuration:

**For IOS**: Add `tel` scheme passed to `canLaunchUrl` as `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` entries in your `Info.plist` file.

Like this:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>tel</string>
</array>
```

**For Android**: Add `tel` scheme passed to `canLaunchUrl` as `queries` entries in your `AndroidManifest.xml` [ie **\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml**] file.

Just like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.flutApp">
     <queries>
         <intent>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
             <data android:scheme="tel" />
         </intent>
     </queries>
   <application
```

3.Import url_launcher to your file: ie `import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';`

4.Code

```
Future<void> _dialNumber(String phoneNumber) async {
final Uri launchUri = Uri(
scheme: 'tel',
path: phoneNumber,
);
await launchUrl(launchUri);
}
```

**Source**: [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)

Comment: The `Info.plist` and `AndoridManifiest` steps are helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

URL launcher has updated their dependency so here is the updated way to do the job. it will work for android ios

```
final Uri launchUri = Uri(
  scheme: 'tel',
  path: number,
);
await launchUrl(launchUri);
```

Who has not used this plugin just imoprt this plugin.

[UrlLauncher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher/example)

Answer (score 3):

Its [too easy](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phone_direct_caller)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_phone_direct_caller/flutter_phone_direct_caller.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: _callNumber,
        child: Text('Call Number'),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

_callNumber() async{
  const number = '08592119XXXX'; //set the number here
  bool res = await FlutterPhoneDirectCaller.callNumber(number);
}
```