# How to make a phone call from a flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, phone-call

I try to make a phone call from my Flutter app. With the following code:

```
UrlLauncher.launch('tel: xxxxxxxx');
```

I found this Function on the GitHub flutter repo: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/4856

But this doesn't work for me. Is this Function still in Flutter and in which package? Or is there a better option to do a phone call from my app?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I dial the phone from Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149073/how-can-i-dial-the-phone-from-flutter)

Comment: Check Latest Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67722228/1318946

Comment: Don't bother for iOS, none of the answers work.

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Call the `launch` method from [url_launcher](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher#pub-pkg-tab-installing) package:

```dart
launch("tel://214324234");
```

---

Here's the complete code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: new Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  Home({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("View"),
        ),
        body: new Center(
          child: new FlatButton(
              onPressed: () => launch("tel://21213123123"),
              child: new Text("Call me")),
        ),
      );
}

void main() {
  runApp(
    new MyApp(),
  );
}
```

Also you can import it and then use

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart' as UrlLauncher;
UrlLauncher.launch("tel://21213123123")
```

Be sure to include an entry for it in the pubspec.yaml file, in the dependencies section:

```
url_launcher: ^1.0.2
```

Comment: And how are you using that in the code? My Problem is that UrlLauncher can't be found.

Comment: U need to  add 'dependencies: url_launcher: "^3.0.0 " in pubspec.yaml and run Package upgrade

Comment: @GermanSaprykin I am getting missing plugin exception even though i added url_launcher: ^4.0.3 in pubspec.yaml file

Comment: @Nudge Don’t forget to install packages via “flutter pub get” and relaunch the app

Comment: @GermanSaprykin I had already installed the package and did package get, but when i completely closed the app and restarted the app then it started working

Comment: Flutter supports hot reloading for dart code, but not native. So an app has to be relaunched for new plugins

Comment: According to https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher#-readme-tab-  , the phone call url should be tel:<phone number>, e.g. tel:+1 555 010 999

Comment: doubt, i have to make direct call instead landing in the phone keypad....!! is there any options like that????

Comment: UPDATE:  launchUrl(Uri.parse("tel:+9112345678"))

Comment: UPDATE: launchUrl(Uri.parse("tel://02025479811"), mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);

Answer (score 17):

**As on 13th August 2022, these are the latest updates :**

*This will work for Calls, SMS, Emails and Websites*

Step 1:

Go to pubspec.yaml under **Project**

> pubspec.yaml

and paste url_launcher : ^6.1.5 under **dependencies:**

( Click on https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher to get the latest version)

```
> dependencies:   
    flutter:
>     sdk: flutter
> 
>   url_launcher: ^6.1.5
```

Then Run -

> Pub Get

Go to AndroidManifest.xml under **android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml**

> AndroidManifest.xml

And paste the following codes for *Phone calls, Sms, Email and Website* under **package="com.example......"** like so -

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.codoweb.your project name">




    <!-- Provide required visibility configuration for API level 30 and above -->
    <queries>
        <!-- If your app opens https URLs -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
        <!-- If your app sends emails -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent>
        <!-- If your app checks for SMS support -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
        </intent>
        <!-- If your app checks for call support -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
```

**Now use the following codes for activating :**

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(const MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Debasis Sil Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.black,
          ),
          home: const MyHomePage(),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text('Debasis Sil Flutter Demo'),
),        
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    final web = Uri.parse(
                      'https://codoweb.com/',
                    );
                    if (await canLaunchUrl(web)) {
                      launchUrl(web);
                    } else {
                      throw 'Could not launch $web';
                    }
                  },
                  child: const Text('Web'),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    final email = Uri(
                      scheme: 'mailto',
                      path: 'codoweb.tech@gmail.com',
                      query: 'subject=Hello&body=Test',
                    );
                    if (await canLaunchUrl(email)) {
                      launchUrl(email);
                    } else {
                      throw 'Could not launch $email';
                    }
                  },
                  child: const Text('Email'),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    final call = Uri.parse('tel:+91 9830268966');
                    if (await canLaunchUrl(call)) {
                      launchUrl(call);
                    } else {
                      throw 'Could not launch $call';
                    }
                  },
                  child: const Text('Call'),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    final sms = Uri.parse('sms:5550101234');
                    if (await canLaunchUrl(sms)) {
                      launchUrl(sms);
                    } else {
                      throw 'Could not launch $sms';
                    }
                  },
                  child: const Text('SMS'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

And Bingo! You are good to go...
Hope this helps :)

I found this motivating that helped me resolve my issue.
Please check :
https://dev-yakuza.posstree.com/en/flutter/url_launcher/

Comment: What about the permissions for iOS?

Answer (score 14):

You should add this in your pubspec.yaml =>  url_launcher: ^5.0.2  then you click Packages get .

in your code you add the import :      import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart' as UrlLauncher;
Hope it works =)

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart' as UrlLauncher;


    UrlLauncher.launch('tel:+${p.phone.toString()}')

        //if mail 
     UrlLauncher.launch('mailto:${p.email}'),
```

Comment: I am guessing this wont connect a call but redirect you to the inbuilt phone dialer app with the phone number is't there a way to actually make a call on click of button from the flutter app itself

Comment: i dont think that there is a way.

Comment: what about the app called truecaller I think it does that right?ofcourse it must have not been built in flutter but some kind of platform channel code could help

Answer (score 11):

To launch the device's dialer, the following code can also be used with exception handling:

```
Future<void> launchPhoneDialer(String contactNumber) async {
  final Uri _phoneUri = Uri(
      scheme: "tel",
      path: contactNumber
  );
  try {
    if (await canLaunch(_phoneUri.toString()))
      await launch(_phoneUri.toString());
  } catch (error) {
    throw("Cannot dial");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you using **url_launcher** and your phone number have plus symbol like "**+1111111111**" for ios you should use Uri class

```
final Uri phoneUrl = Uri(
  scheme: 'tel',
  path: '+11111111111',
);

if (await canLaunch(phoneUrl.toString())) {
  await launch(phoneUrl.toString());
} else {
  throw "Can't phone that number.";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me

use [this plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phone_direct_caller#-readme-tab-)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'dart:async';
    
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_phone_direct_caller/flutter_phone_direct_caller.dart';
    
    void main() => runApp(new MyApp());
    
    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
    }
    
    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
      TextEditingController _numberCtrl = new TextEditingController();
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _numberCtrl.text = "085921191121";
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new MaterialApp(
          home: new Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(
              title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
            ),
            body: new Column(
              children:<Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: _numberCtrl,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "Phone Number"
                    ),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  ),
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text("Test Call"),
                  onPressed: () async{
                    FlutterPhoneDirectCaller.callNumber(_numberCtrl.text);
                  },
                )
              ]
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Did you tried this on iPhone ? On Android is working on iPhone is failing.

Answer (score 5):

**[url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)** is universal package for launching url, dialing number and sending mail.

1. Add `url_launcher: ^5.5.2` to pubspec.yaml file and run `flutter pub get`
2. Import package `import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';`
3. Define function:

```
void launchUrl(String url) async {
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    launch(url);
  } else {
    throw "Could not launch $url";
  }
}
```

4. Call your universal function for different purposes:

```
//for launching url
launchUrl("HTTP://example.com");

// for dial phone number
launchUrl("tel:+99364921507"); 

// for sending email
launchUrl("mailto:zehinz@gmail.com?subject=Meeting&body=Can we meet via Google Meet");
```

Answer (score 5):

Create a function like this. All above solutions are deprecated with new version.

import URL launch package top of the file

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

 // Make phone call flutter app
      Future<void> _makePhoneCall(String phoneNumber) async {
        final Uri launchUri = Uri(
          scheme: 'tel',
          path: phoneNumber,
        );
        await launchUrl(launchUri);
      }
```

Call that functions as same as below. in your action call EX: onPressed
Parse your phone number to this function as a string.

```
_makePhoneCall(phoneNumber);
```

Add below package to your pub file

```
url_launcher: ^6.1.5
```

Add Below Lines to manifest.xml for get permistions

```
<queries>
    <!-- If your app checks for SMS support -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="sms" />
    </intent>
    <!-- If your app checks for call support -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Answer (score 4):

I am able to make a phone call by bringing up the system phone app and CONNECT A CALL:

Here's what you need to do:

1. pubspec.yaml add package:

   intent:
2. main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intent/intent.dart' as android_intent;
import 'package:intent/action.dart' as android_action;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);


  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return (Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
                 onPressed: _launchURL,
                 child: Text('Dial a number'),
               )
      ),
    ));
  }
}


_launchURL() async {
  // Replace 12345678 with your tel. no.

  android_intent.Intent()
    ..setAction(android_action.Action.ACTION_CALL)
    ..setData(Uri(scheme: "tel", path: "12345678"))
    ..startActivity().catchError((e) => print(e));
}
```

Then, after running this app and click the "Dial a number", the System Phone App will bring up and make a call.  (Unlike url_launcher, you don't need to press the Green Call button in the System Phone App)

Comment: so what about IOS?

Comment: @Kenneth Li, I would also like to know how to do it in iOS.

Comment: I can't find any solution to 'press the Green Button' automatically in IOS

Comment: @KennethLi Hi, how to get info about events like when calling will ended. Do you know maybe? I really need this.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

> **url_launcher: 6.1.6**

In previous versions 
**canLaunch() 

launch()** 

methods are deprecated. 
below code is as per the new version.

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class CallUtils {
   CallUtils._();

   static Future<void> openDialer(String phoneNumber) async {
      Uri callUrl = Uri.parse('tel:=$phoneNumber');
      if (await canLaunchUrl(callUrl)) {
         await launchUrl(callUrl);
      } else {
         throw 'Could not open the dialler.';
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Will it work on a simulator?

Comment: @Soropromo no it will not

Answer (score 2):

Just `url_launcher: ^ latest Version` in Pubspec.yamal

Note: Before Pub get or Upgrade delete Pubspec.lock some time it gives unwanted problems.

Import package import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

```
//for launching URL

launchUrl("HTTP://website.com");


// for dial phone number

launchUrl("tel:+91963852741"); 


// for sending email

launchUrl("mailto:mail@gmail.com?subject=Meeting&body=Can we meet via Google Meet");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call directly by this package [flutter_phone_direct_caller](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phone_direct_caller)

***Create a function and pass the mobile number value  :***

```
  _callNumber(String mobile) async {
     await FlutterPhoneDirectCaller.callNumber(mobile);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by two ways:-

- **url_launcher** package will be used to implement phone call using the default app of your mobile phone. This package will auto direct the phone to the default phone call making app and open the dialer screen to make the call.
- **flutter_phone_direct_caller** package is not the best package but we can  implement direct phone calls directly from our phone without the intermediate dialer.

Install the following dependencies inside your pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  flutter_phone_direct_caller: ^1.0.1
  url_launcher: ^5.7.10
```

Making Phone Calls using the "**flutter_phone_direct_caller**" : plugin
To implement the phone call using this plugin is really very easy. This package provides us FlutterPhoneDirectCaller class that provides us callNumber() method that takes a phone number.

```
_callNumber(String phoneNumber) async {
 String number = phoneNumber;
 await FlutterPhoneDirectCaller.callNumber(number);
}
```

You can implement it in your button as follows

```
RaisedButton(
  child: Text("Call"),
  onPressed: () {
    _callNumber(textEditingController.text);
  },

)
```

Making Phone Calls using the "**url_launcher**": plugin
This package provides us launch(URL) method that takes an URL with schema. Scheme is very essential as it directs the URL. In the case of phone calls, we use ‘tel:’ schema.

```
_launchPhoneURL(String phoneNumber) async {
  String url = 'tel:' + phoneNumber;
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

and to raised button:-

```
RaisedButton(
  child: Text("Call"),
  onPressed: () {
    _launchPhoneURL(textEditingController.text);
  },
)
```

IF you need advanced features you can use "**flutter_voip_kit**", it is very new library, I have also not used it but it looks promising at first galance..