# Phone call in flutter

Tags: flutter

My phone call method is not working. When I give my mobile number directly its working. However when I pass from my DB it's not working... It's always dialing 662453... 
Here is my code :

```
void _launchCaller(String mobile) async {
    //debugPrint(mobile);
    //UrlLauncher.launch('tel:${contact.phone}');
    const url = "tel:mobile";
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
```

Comment: you can check this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45523370/making-phone-call-from-a-flutter-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45523370/making-phone-call-from-a-flutter-app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that a syntax error? "tel:mobile" will not work, "tel:$mobile" will.

Also 662453 is how the "mobile" word appear on the keyboard of the phone. (look the letters under every number)

Comment: Thank you ..I got it by using URLlauncher.launch('tel:$mobile);