# Call Phone number Function in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I have designed a function to call a number on a pressed icon.
But it cannot launch url

```
 _callMe() async {
 print("Phone +91${store_phone}");
 var uri = 'tel:+91${store_phone}';
 if (await canLaunch(uri)) {
   await launch(uri);
 } else {
   throw 'Could not launch $uri';
 }
}
```

It Prints the error
Unhandled Exception: Could not launch +919919195521

any help guys?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45523502/8023701 have a look at this

Answer (score 1):

```
 Uri numberUri;
     numberUri = Uri(scheme: 'tel', path: phoneNumber);

    if (!await launchUrl(numberUri)) throw 'Could not launch $numberUri';
```

Use the above method to open phone dialer

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you. used [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package

```
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 18.0),
  child: InkWell(
    child: Text(
      ' +91 888-888-8888',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 15,
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    ),
    onTap: () => launch('tel:${8888888888}'),
  ),
)
```