# How to open contact menu in flutter?

Tags: flutter

how to open a contact or phone call or keypad menu using dart in flutter inside the icon button inside onPressed?

[image]

`new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.call, color: Colors.blue,), onPressed: null),`

Thanks.

Comment: There is currently nothing in Flutter. I don't know Android well enough if something like that can be achieved with intents, but in Flutter you can use https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/contacts_service#-readme-tab- to show your own contacts dialog, or otherwise https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/android_intent

Comment: Yeah if you want to show the system contacts app, you'd need to launch a new intent, using the methods @GünterZöchbauer already linked to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I dial the phone from Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149073/how-can-i-dial-the-phone-from-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

As [Rajesh Jr. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50642940/2076880):

> This method will open the dialer :
>
> ```
> _launchCaller() async {
>     const url = "tel:1234567";   
>     if (await canLaunch(url)) {
>        await launch(url);
>     } else {
>       throw 'Could not launch $url';
>     }   
> }
> ```
>
> EDIT:
>
> In case anybody facing errors:
>
> Add url_launcher: in the pubspec.yaml & run flutter get
>
> Also import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';